# How to win a Rot victory in Armello?

Tags: armello

How am I supposed to win with a Rot Victory, knowing that the only way to earn Rot points is with cards, but the King gains Rot points every turn.

So how can I have more Rot points than him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cards are not the only way to gain Rot.  Per the [wiki](http://armello.wikia.com/wiki/Rot_(stat)), the other ways to gain Rot are:

- By equipping the Spoil amulet. (Although you need to have already won a Rot victory to get this)
- Any hero that is slain by a Bane will gain one point of Rot.
- Any hero that is already corrupted (5+ rot) will gain 1 rot when killing a Bane
- The King's declaration Blood Moon will give all heroes 1 point of rot.

Comment: With these notes in mind from the answer, it seems the strategy is to fight losing battles with banes and use rot cards when possible to get to 5 (or more) rot as fast as possible, gaining at least one rot or more every other turn to keep up with the King.  Once you're past the 5 threshold you need to fight winning bane battles and make your way into the castle.

Comment: @MadMAxJr Once I have reached the castle, do I still have to fight the king?

Comment: @Maxime Yes.  The Rot victory is the same as the Combat victory.  The only difference is who has more Rot.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's worth noting that the King gains Rot every night, i.e. every other turn.

Rot victories are the most unreliable victory in Armello. Sometimes even a setup designed for a Rot victory will need to abandon it and go for something else (usually prestige). Other times you will get lucky, end up with plenty of Rot, and go for a rot victory from there.

Suiciding into Banes is often a bad idea. It's an inefficient use of turns since you have to return to clan grounds and you lose prestige. There are exceptions- if you're going to die at dawn anyway or sometimes for getting that 5th point (and potentially the 6th in the same battle if you kill each other). Generally though, if your strategy involves killing yourself more than once to gain Rot, you should be going for another victory type.

If you want lots of rot, you want to be drawing as many cards, (ideally spells which have a far better chance of causing rot) as possible. This means having high wits, using every card you can, and burning the rest whether it helps you or not.

Heroes that are particularly suited for a Rot victory are:

- Fang. Starting with 1 rot (for a total of 3 with Spoil) makes it much easier to get Corrupted. His ability allows him to kill banes for more rot without taking any damage or kill the king without worrying about dying in the process.
- Sargon. High Wits, good Spirit, and you can see the top card of decks and take them if they give rot.
- Yordana. High spirit, decent wit, and an ability for cycling expensive spells so you can draw more.
- Twiss. High Wits and Spirit. You can also steal cards from other players (which often end up being rot cards they don't want).

Comment: Fang really seems to make Rot viable.  Starts with a rot point and is geared around winning fights, often.